# How to efficiently detect and rename downloaded files in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, file-handling, file-rename

I am working on a Python script to download multiple CSV files from a website and want to rename them as soon as they are fully downloaded. Initially, I used a long waiting period to ensure the download completion, but I faced issues with small files that finish downloading quickly. To tackle this, I attempted to detect the ".crdownload" file, waiting until it disappears to rename the last downloaded file. However, I noticed that this method doesn't work consistently when the internet speed is fast, as small files are not detected for the ".crdownload" extension.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this situation and ensure that all downloaded files are successfully renamed without unnecessary waiting? I would appreciate any suggestions or alternative approaches to efficiently handle file download detection and renaming in Python.

`def download_button(self):

```
    #click download button
    xpath = '/html/body/app-root/app-layout/section/app-detail/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/button'
    self.hf.click(xpath)
    
    print('download button clicked')
    # Wait for the file to be downloaded before renaming the same
    max_download_time = 300
    
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, max_download_time).until(lambda driver:self.is_file_downloaded())
    except TimeoutException:
        print(f"CRDOWNLOAD file did not appear within {max_download_time} seconds.")
        return
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, max_download_time).until(lambda driver: not self.is_file_downloaded())
        
    except TimeoutException:
        print(f"File download did not complete within {max_download_time} seconds.")
        
def is_file_downloaded(self):   #helps detecting if the file is in downloading state
    return any(filename.endswith('.crdownload') for filename in os.listdir(self.download_dir))

    
def rename_file(self,prefix):
            
    new_file_name = f"{prefix} {self.full_college_name}.csv"
    new_file_path = os.path.join(self.download_dir, new_file_name)
    
    # Check if a file with the same name already exists
    if os.path.exists(new_file_path):
        os.remove(new_file_path)
        print(f"Existing file '{new_file_name}' deleted.")

    # Find the latest downloaded file in the download directory
    time.sleep(1)
    latest_file = max(
        [os.path.join(self.download_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(self.download_dir)],
        key=os.path.getctime
    )

    # Rename the downloaded file to the custom name
    
    os.rename(latest_file, new_file_path)
    

    print(f'Data saved for {prefix} {self.full_college_name}')`
```

Comment: you could create a separate thread that occasionally checks the directory contents for changes.

Comment: Maybe I should try to check if the total number of .csv files has increased by 1, then it will rename the last one instead of waiting and detecting if the file has been downloaded.

Comment: But for the above approach, I need to empty the folder before start downloading.

Comment: Why?  Just capture the contents of the directory before starting the download and then once downloading has started you can check the contents again to see if there are any additional files from the first check